# BOX REST end point : How to get Membership ID associated with a particular user and group combination

Tags: box-api, box

Is there any end point for getting Membership ID associated with a particular User ID and Group ID.

I know we can get all the Membership ID’s associated with User or a Group (Ref: https://box-content.readme.io/reference#get-all-group-memberships-for-a-user).  But what I am interested in is to get only one membership ID associated with a User ID and Group ID combination.

Parsing through current response of all the membership ID’s is very costly affair for me, that’s the reason I was trying to find if there are any other alternatives.

Comment: Can you say more about what makes your current solution costly?

Comment: I will have more than 1000 users on Box. These users I will have to get from Box to my application.
Now these users may be present in 10 different groups. 
So for getting these membership ID of a all the users and for all the groups will be costly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query for a specific membership based on the user ID and group ID. As I think you're probably aware your options are to:

1. [Get all members of a group](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#get-the-membership-list-for-a-group) and look for the particular user among the memberships. This may be the best option if your groups typically have few members.
2. [Get all group memberships for a user](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#get-all-group-memberships-for-a-user) and look for the particular membership among the groups. This may be the best option if your users typically belong to few groups.

Since those endpoints return arrays you can take advantage of [pagination](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#api-docs-directory) to reduce the overall number of requests:

> Endpoints that return arrays support `limit` and `offset` as URL parameters. `Limit` defines the maximum number of records that will be returned on a page. The number of records is not guaranteed to be the number specified as visibility rules may filter out items. To avoid duplicates being returned we recommend the following logic:
>
> To retrieve the next page, set `offset=offset+limit`
>   If total count from previous response is >= the new offset, you are done, no need to ask for another page
>   Note that `offset` is zero based, defaults for `limit` vary by endpoint.